# 文字列のリストを文字列に変換するには...?

Tags: python

Pythonで

```
list = ["a","bbb1234","aaaaa","eeee"]
```

というリストがあった場合に
これに対して何らかの処理を施して

```
'["a","bbb1234","aaaaa","eeee"]'
```

という文字列に変換したいです。
前後のカッコまで含めたいです。
どうするのが最も効率的に出来ますか？

Comment: `str(lst)` ですかね。ダブルクォートではなくてシングルクォートになってしまいますけれども。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsonですか？

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: lst = ["a","bbb1234","aaaaa","eeee"]

In [3]: json.dumps(lst)
Out[3]: '["a", "bbb1234", "aaaaa", "eeee"]'
```